# Broken Camera Zoom In Render

Tags: rendering, camera

Anyone knows any possible way to fix the issue where my camera in render will be 10x more times zoomed onto something than it was originally in the viewport (ps - i know bout selecting different cameras..)

ps-i now also noticed that for some reason if i render single image in some parts of the video the sccene is too bright while in another itss too dark..  ://

The drive link to the file..

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mrdpXDYf0ioREBrAJiDH5LpX-2QLuZrd/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps, it is the online equivalent of shouting, is [harder to read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Readability) and may be [considered rude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing). You can use the [edit] button below to change you text into regular case.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's a camera problem. You have a *Collection 10* that is hidden in the viewport but enabled in render, it makes objects appear in render:

[image]